# Check if day is in current quarter of the year (crypto)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Checking if a day is within the current month & Co  is obvious

e.g.       `bool currentMonth = year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time)`

But, honestly, how do I check if a day / chosen timeframe is within the current quarter of the year?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in the exact same way , just we have to divide the months by 3

```
bool currentQuarter = year(timenow) == year(time) and (math.floor((month(timenow)-1)/3)== math.floor((month(time)-1)/3))
```

Comment: Sometimes its like I need a fresh brain. Thanks!